# Powershell and previous folder versions

Tags: powershell, shadow-copy

I have a problem in powershell when iam trying to copy Previous Versions from a folder, Frankly, I do not really know how to do.

Scenario:

In Device D, I have enabled shadow copies, in this device, I have multiple folders.

FolderA

FolderB

FolderC

If i use Win32_ShadowCopy i get a ton of information but nothing pointing to where Folder B is located so that i can use get-childitems to retrive the information.

If I would use" Get-childitem -Force -Recurse -Path D$\@GMT-2017.10.13-15.00.00\Folders\FolderB "  I get the path to the last version that was copied, but how do I get this path in Win32_ShadowCopy or even see it?

How would you solve this scenario?

Comment: It would need to be `\\localhost\D$\@GMT-2017.10.13-15.00.00\Folders\FolderB`.  You should be able to `cd` or `pushd` to the folder if you've got the hostname in the URI.

Comment: thanks for the reply Bacon Bits